# Degree of freedom - Lorentz transfomation reduces it?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, degrees-of-freedom, gauge

I am having a real difficult to counting degree of freedom. In fact, I notice that sometimes I am confused about what exactly we count as DoF, and what we do not count.

See, for example, the electromagnetic field. The potential has a gauge symmetry

$$\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} = 0$$

Now, initially, in $d=4$, this potential has $4$ dof, but the gauge symmetry (1 eq) decrease it by 1, so we have $3$ now. If we study the equations of motion, we will see the further condition for massless particles

$$\epsilon_{\mu} k^{\mu} = 0$$

Which restrict even more the dof, so we have 2 now. Ok. What is confusing me is that, sometimes, I have seen people (see for example asperanz's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130942/)) using the diffeomorphism of the spacetime to restrict the dof as well, and this is confusing me. How can it restrict something? I mean, if so, $A_{\mu}$ has 4 transformation ($\mu = 0,...3$) and has no dof?

Comment: Gauge symmetry does not reduce the degrees of freedom, however, fixing some particular gauge does.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119756/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31143/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395284/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427816/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic The question is about diffeomorphism of the spacetime, not about EM itself. EM was just an example

Comment: Diffeomorphism of the spacetime only applies to GR, not EM/YM gauge theory.